# How to rename the pictures after unzip file with the name based on unzip file's name with python

Tags: python, rename, unzip, zip, file-rename

I have zip files in folder A and I want to unzip it and rename the pictures in the unzip file based on the name of the zip files then move it to folder B. But I don't know how to rename it. Please help!

I have script like this:

```
path = r'C:\Users\A'
path_to_extract = r'C:\Users\B'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if '.zip' in str(file):
            file_path = path + '/' + file
            zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') 
            zip_ref.extractall(path_to_extract)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, don't forget to put the extension behind the filename

```py
import os

os.rename(r'file path with old filename',r'file path with new filename')
```